# Processing data frame column with mixed entries of % and undefined fractions with 0 and *

Tags: r

I have inherited a spreadsheet, read in as a data frame, with ~ 10 columns and ~ 400 rows.

In the example below, for one of those columns, you can see that it contains a mix of ***both*** percentage values ***and*** fractions.

Furthermore, such fractions may contain **' * '** **and/or** **' 0 '**, and in the numerator **and/or** denominator, as shown under the **OBSERVED** column of the example cases shown below.

I seek your help with R code for homogenizing all entries in such columns to decimal numbers, as shown under the **EXPECTED** column for the examples below,
and then repeat this process over all columns in the data frame.

For my analysis, it is quite OK to consider missing values (*) as zeroes (0).

**EXAMPLE CASES:**

**OBSERVED      vs. EXPECTED**

```
"0.0%"              0.0
"9.5%"              0.095
"5 / 10"            0.5
"* / 16"            0.0
"0 / 12"            0.0
NA                  0.0
"0 / *"             0.0
"* / *"             0.0
```

So far what I've tried are as follows (in this same order):

**Step 1. Replace * (missing data) with 0 (zero)** - works OK

```
CFP4_REPLACE_Asterisk_w_Zero <- gsub("\\*","0",play.df$CFP4)
```

**Step 2. Convert % to decimals** - works OK only on entries with % symbol, but converts fractions to NA

```
CFP4_ConvPerc2Dcml <- as.numeric(sub("%", "",CFP4_REPLACE_Asterisk_w_Zero,fixed=TRUE))/100
```

**Step 3. Convert fractions into decimal values** - syntax shown below, works OK I think, but in this sequential order of steps, the fractions have been already converted to NA, so it is meaningless to execute here...right?

```
CFP4_ConvFrct2Dcml <- sapply(CFP4_ConvPerc2Dcml, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
```

If I reverse the relative order of steps 2 and 3, that doesn't help either. I've taken a break from R, and would appreciate any (detailed) help. TIA!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post R questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @YOLO - Hope that is better, and that someone can help me with my question. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this function :

```
standardize_numbers <- function(x) {
   #Initialize a new vector
   new_vec <- numeric(length = length(x))
   #Get indices where "%" is present
   inds1 <- grepl('%', x)
   #Replace % value
   new_vec[inds1] <- as.numeric(sub('%', '', x[inds1]))/100
   #Get indices where "*" or "/" is present
   inds2 <- grepl('\\*|/', x)
   #Replace "*" with 0
   value2 <- gsub('\\*', '0', x[inds2])
   #Remove whitespace
   value2 <- gsub('\\s', '', value2)
   #Use eval parse to get value2 as numbers. 
   new_vec[inds2] <- sapply(value2, function(y) eval(parse(text = y)))
   new_vec
}

x <- c("0.0%", "9.5%", "5 / 10", "* / 16", "0 / 12", NA, "0 / *", "* / *")
standardize_numbers(x)
#[1] 0.000 0.095 0.500 0.000 0.000 0.000   NaN   NaN
```

You can apply this to multiple columns using `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your function. When I tried your exact same syntax, the error message i am getting is:  

`> standardize_numbers(x)  

Error in sub("%", "", x[inds1]) : object 'inds1' not found`

Comment: I would add one missing line after new vector initialization:

`# Get indices where % is present
   inds1 <- grepl('%', x)`

Then it matches your output, do you concur? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that line while putting this into function. Updated the answer.